# css works in Firefox, not in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I recently adjusted the width of a div via css. It works in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Here's the code:

```
.the_content {
    padding-left: 60px !important;
    padding-right: 40px !important;
}

.the_content {
    padding-left: 60px !important;
    padding-right: 40px !important;
}

.the_content.post.type-post.hentry.excerpt.clearfix {
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
```

Am I missing something that Chrome isn't picking up?

Thanks,

Comment: When you say that this feature "doesn't work", what exactly do you mean? There are a lot of different meanings for this. To help get your problem understood by other users, try adding some code or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help.

Comment: .the_content post type-post hentry excerpt clearfix remove this line

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, there is no reason that i can suspect why it is not working in chrome by looking at code you provided. you are using paddings in little duplicated manner. try to club them first. how about explaining it in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: What's the first line for? It's illegal css code. Try to remove it.

Comment: All good points. I'm sorry that I'm a total noob at this, but I really appreciate everyone's help even in just informing me of my ignorance. I used the above code to shrink the .div for the blog on this site: alchemyondemand.com/top-10-words-that-capture-readers-attention I don't understand why calling the div class would work in Firefox but not in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Provide HTML for more clarity on the issue. You repeated the css classes in multiple places.

Try this:

```
.the_content
 {
 padding-left: 60px !important;
 padding-right: 40px !important;
 }

 .the_content.post.type-post.hentry.excerpt.clearfix {
  padding-left: 60px;
  padding-right: 40px;
 }
```

Comment: All good points. I'm sorry that I'm a total noob at this, but I really appreciate everyone's help even in just informing me of my ignorance. I used the above code to shrink the .div for the blog on this site: http://www.alchemyondemand.com/top-10-words-that-capture-readers-attention/
I don't understand why calling the div class would work in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The first line in your posted code

```
.the_content post type-post hentry excerpt clearfix /* Remove spaces if this is a single class style. if multiple user ","*/
```

Doesn’t have opening and closing curly brackets, this will render all the settings below it useless.

if your going to have a blank link but with the style names

```
.the_content post type-post hentry excerpt clearfix {} /*<------------*/
.the_content {
    padding-left: 60px !important;
    padding-right: 40px !important;
}

.the_content {
    padding-left: 60px !important;
    padding-right: 40px !important;
}

.the_content.post.type-post.hentry.excerpt.clearfix {
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
```